# Microsoft Graph, Registering a Schema Extension

Tags: azure-active-directory, office365, microsoft-graph-api

I'm building an internal meeting room app that uses the Microsoft Graph API and I would like to extend Event objects with a Schema Extension.

Documentation:

- [API Reference](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/schemaextension_post_schemaextensions)
- [Tutorial Example](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/extensibility_schema_groups)

However when running a query to register a new schema extension, I am receiving this HTTP response:

```
{
    "url": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/schemaExtensions",
    "status": "403 Forbidden",
    "headers": {
        "request-id": "e1e36210-6c4c-4ed8-afb1-c9ee6f6362ed",
        "client-request-id": "e1e36210-6c4c-4ed8-afb1-c9ee6f6362ed",
        "x-ms-ags-diagnostic": "{\"ServerInfo\":{\"DataCenter\":\"North Europe\",\"Slice\":\"SliceA\",\"ScaleUnit\":\"001\",\"Host\":\"AGSFE_IN_2\",\"ADSiteName\":\"DUB\"}}",
        "duration": "742.4624"
    },
    "body": {
        "error": {
            "code": "Authorization_RequestDenied",
            "message": "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.",
            "innerError": {
                "request-id": "e1e36210-6c4c-4ed8-afb1-c9ee6f6362ed",
                "date": "2017-05-10T10:05:37"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I can confirm that my application has the prerequisite scope permission of `Directory.AccessAsUser.All` and it's also been more than 16 hours since adding this permission. I have also got verified domains, so the namespace should be OK per the documentation reference.

My API query in code:

```
Outlook.test({
    version: 'beta',
    resource: 'schemaExtensions',
    method: 'POST',
    body: {
        id: 'thehivegroup_beethere',
        description: 'Extension for event presence status',
        targetTypes: [ 'Event' ],
        properties: [
            { name: 'checkIn', type: 'String' },
            { name: 'checkOut', type: 'String' }
        ]
    }
})
.then(result => console.log(result), err => console.error(err))
```

Which results in a POST with the JSON encoded in the body and headers with authorization token to the URL `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/schemaExtensions`.

I have tried different IDs, such as `beethere`, which resulted in a namespace error, so I know this ought to be working fine.

There are no other scope permissions I am aware of that I need to enable here as well. The error is just too vague for me to figure out *what* privileges are insufficient here.

---

**EDIT:** Have manually run the query in the [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer#) as an Admin in the tenant, added the scope permissions required for the API and some extra ones in case, but the query for registration of Schema Extensions still does not work, with the same error message as the application receives. So it is definitely not a problem in my code, but the Microsoft Graph API. Is there a contact or way to ask microsoft to look into the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Graph Explorer is able to add an extension.
You will need to create an app in your tenant and set the owner in the payload to the client id of your app.

[more on this](https://blogs.aaddevsup.xyz/2018/08/21/how-to-create-a-new-schema-extension-using-the-microsoft-graph-explorer/)

Answer (score 2):

Directory.AccessAsUser.All is a delegated permission only (it must be delegated because it grants access to directory based APIs as the signed-in user's access rights).  It doesn't show up in the roles claim because it isn't an application permission.

As far as I know, right know, you cannot use the application flow (client credentials) to create a schema extension, and you need to use the "code authorization" flow.  Please let us know if this is a requirement.  Additionally we'd love to know if you want to see an experience for schema definition registration as part of the application registration...

Also you CANNOT currently create a schema extension definition (or manage it) through Graph Explorer. For you to created a definition, you must either be an admin or the owner of the app creating the extension definition AND the creation request must also come from that application (which cannot be graph explorer).  We may look at relaxing this last constraint.

If you want to see a code snippet for this it's available here (although it's a UWP c# app, not JS): https://github.com/microsoftgraph/uwp-csharp-snippets-rest-sample.

Also schema extensions is now GA, and available in the v1.0 endpoint.

Hope this helps,

Comment: Thanks, that explains the nuances in the way delegated permissions work.

Would like to see Graph Explorer able to handle delegated perms.
Alternatively, being able to register and manage schema extensions not exclusively via REST / Graph API. Considering how rare it is to manage schema extension, having to build a lot of code and logic and a whole admin user interface for every single applications' schema extensions, seems over the top. Could this be managed in the Azure Portal somehow or have a single-purpose application for managing schema extensions? Once a schema is GA it can be reused

Comment: Sure Nexii.  Please add a request for a UI (either in app registration or another experience) in UserVoice: https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/category/101632-microsoft-graph-o365-rest-api.  We should be fixing the ability to use Graph Explorer sooner.

Comment: Meant to add, prior to fixing so you can create/manage you schema extension definitions in Graph Explorer, you can use Postman to perform these operations (you'll need to use the AAD v2 endpoint to acquire access tokens to Microsoft Graph)

Answer (score 1):

This schema extensions creating REST works well for me. Please ensure that the token contains `Directory.AccessAsUser.All` permission. You can parse the token check the `scp` claim in it from this [site](https://jwt.io/).

Comment: However, regardless, the exact same REST call to the schema extension failed in Graph Explorer, which we granted and consented admin permission on an admin account for the `Directory.AccessAsUser.All` permission scope.

Does it mean the Graph Explorers' token doesn't contain the scope correctly either?

I'll check the access token on the application for the roles and see what I can figure out with the server-based authorisation flow.

Comment: Okay, I'm using the Client Credentials flow for the application and I don't see any 'scp' but the roles array is missing the `Directory.AccessAsUser.All` permission scope in the access token.

Comment: I'm baffled, as we pre-configured that same permission scope in the Azure Portal for the application already, but for some reason we don't receive it for our token. I can try moving to the Azure AD v2.0, but our application is built around the current adal-node client library and I suspect there is no JS library for this new version that supports client credentials.